# Updates table missing in Joomla 3

Tags: mysql, joomla, joomla3.2

Joomla 3.x comes with a handy Update Joomla extension, this updates any extensions on the site including the Joomla core. Unfortunately on some installs (primarily one's migrated from Joomla 1.5 to Joomla 3.x) the "#__updates" table is missing from the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After spending hours trawling the internet, I worked out the missing tables and have written the following MySQL query which solves this issue:

```
DROP table IF EXISTS #__updates;
CREATE TABLE `#__updates` (
  `update_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `update_site_id` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `extension_id` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `name` varchar(100) DEFAULT '',
  `description` text NOT NULL,
  `element` varchar(100) DEFAULT '',
  `type` varchar(20) DEFAULT '',
  `folder` varchar(20) DEFAULT '',
  `client_id` tinyint(3) DEFAULT '0',
  `version` varchar(32) DEFAULT '',
  `data` text NOT NULL,
  `detailsurl` text NOT NULL,
  `infourl` text NOT NULL,
  `extra_query` VARCHAR(1000) DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`update_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Available Updates';
```

Comment: For `extra_query`, you should be using `VARCHAR(1000) DEFAULT '',` rather than `text NOT NULL,` And the last line doesn't need the auto increment ;)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, more than once (with new installed Joomla 3.x). Joomla reported `x_updates doesn't exist`.

The query provided here faulted with `x_updates already exists`. Only after adding `DROP table IF EXISTS 'x_updates';` before the code the table was created.

This may mean some plugins have to be reinstalled in Joomla and other work using this plugins is lost.

Answer (score 0):

Just look at the [original code](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/staging/installation/sql/mysql/joomla.sql#L1750), it's rather simple and it takes 2 minutes.

```
--
-- Table structure for table `#__updates`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `#__updates` (
  `update_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `update_site_id` int(11) DEFAULT 0,
  `extension_id` int(11) DEFAULT 0,
  `name` varchar(100) DEFAULT '',
  `description` text NOT NULL,
  `element` varchar(100) DEFAULT '',
  `type` varchar(20) DEFAULT '',
  `folder` varchar(20) DEFAULT '',
  `client_id` tinyint(3) DEFAULT 0,
  `version` varchar(32) DEFAULT '',
  `data` text NOT NULL,
  `detailsurl` text NOT NULL,
  `infourl` text NOT NULL,
  `extra_query` VARCHAR(1000) DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`update_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Available Updates';
```

Comment: This table doesn't exist on sites which have been automatically migrated from Joomla 1.5 to Joomla 3.2, hence the fix.